# Combinatorics Question on investing in stock.

Tags: combinatorics

Stumbled across this in a past probability exam paper for my course. Any ideas?

An investor wishes to invest 12K in two different stocks. Each investment must
be made in units of 1K. How many different possible investment strategies does
he have if he wants to include both stocks in his portfolio (i.e. to make a minimum
investment of 1K in each stock)?

Answer (score 0):

There are 11 choices. (1,11) (2,10)....(11,1)

Comment: Okay. Is there any sort of formula you can use to get this? For example how would you go about doing it if there are three different stocks?

Comment: @user113226:  It is a [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem.

Comment: Yes, Ross is right. In this case the formula comes out to (n-1) choose (k-1) ways to invest n thousand dollars into k different stocks.

Answer (score 0):

11 choices assumes investing all of the money at the same time. But the numbers (12K in 1K pieces) suggest that this investment may spread through, say, one year, 1K being invested every month.

This results in $2^{12}$ options, but two of them (always stock A and always stock B) are not allowed. Therefore, $2^{12}-2 = 4094$ different investment sequences are possible under this interpretation.